# Neutrinos and Speed of light

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, neutrinos

Einstein's Special Theory of relativity postulates that the speed of light is same for all frames.

Suppose a neutrino is there moving at the speed of light. Then will that neutrino also be flowing with same speed for all frames or is this a special property of EM waves?

Comment: I have attempted to clarify the question, please let me know if this is not what you meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly:

*in a vaccuum

*inertial

> Einstein's Special Theory of relativity postulates that the speed of light in a vacuum is same for all inertial frames.

---

> suppose a neutrino is there moving at the speed of light

For a neutrino to move at $c$, it has to be a massless particle. <s>We're not sure of that yet.</s> Apparently the existence of  neutrino oscillations prove that neutrinos have some rest mass (h/t Neuneck).

But yes, if any particle moves at $c$ in *one* inertial frame, it does so in *all* inertial frames. An example of this would be the gluon.

However, if the neutrino has mass, it will never be able to reach $c$ in any inertial frame. Particles going at subliminal speeds cannot be sped up to $c$, and particles moving at $c$ cannot be slowed down.

Comment: Actually, having observed neutrino oscillations from all families to all others we are sure that neutrinos do have a non-zero rest mass.

Comment: @Neuneck: Hmm, true. I'll edit that in in a moment.